# Приложение .NetCore на Linux сервере не видит XmlUrlResolver

Tags: c#, linux, windows, xml, валидация

Пишу приложение для валидации xml по xsd схеме. Пытаюсь скомпилировать xsd схему, включающая import и include других схем.

```
XmlSchema schema;
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

XmlReaderSettings xsdSet = new XmlReaderSettings()
{
    XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver()
};

using (var xsdReader = XmlReader.Create(xsdSchemaPath, xsdSet))
{
    schema = XmlSchema.Read(xsdReader, null);
} 
schemaSet.Add(schema);
schemaSet.Compile();
```

На свой машине (windows) без проблем компилируется, schemaSet показывает Count = 5, но переношу приложение на сервер (linux) и при компиляции ошибка Type ... is not declared, schemaSet.Count = 1. По какой-то причине `XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver()`
не выполняется или выполняется некорректно. Библиотека System.Xml.ReaderWriter. Также прописано `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);`. Не очень хочется писать свой Resolver. В какую сторону копать?

Заранее спасибо.